# Visual Studio C++ Standard Regex get tag till whitespace

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have this string:

```
LOWS 111150Z 38005KT 320V050
```

I need the KT Tag **38005KT**. The KT Tag can be in the following formats:

- 18010KT
- 35012G20KT
- 00000KT
- VRB16G28KT

I tried it with the following regex:

```
regex wind("[^\\\s].*KT");
```

But I get the following string:

```
LOWS 111150Z 38005KT
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regex wind( "[0-9a-zA-Z]*KT" );
```

will give you the desired string.

It means unlimited times `0-9` and `a-z` and `A-Z` before the `KT`.

So whitespaces and everything else is not included.

Comment: Hy, thank your for your quick reply. I forget that the KT can have different formats. I edited the main posted and added format examples. How I can handle so much formats? I want to get everything from the whitespace till the KT.

Comment: @user2644964 I've updated it to include small letters and big letters as well.